# Bluetooth L2CAP server on Windows 10 (c#)

Tags: c#-4.0, bluetooth, windows-10, l2cap

With iOS 11, Apple added support for MFI-free L2CAP protocol. I need to implement L2CAP server on C# (Windows 10) to allow ios client L2CAP connections. Does anyone know a good (or even any) reference (sample code / example) of L2CAP server implementation in C#? Thanks in advance.